# kernel Module on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi4

I am new to kernel Module and trying to build a kernel Module on Rpi, for simple Hello World :
I am running this using VScode by connecting my RPI through SSH with VScode!

Following is my code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>               // Needed by all modules
#include <linux/kernel.h>               // Needed for KERN_ALERT
#include <linux/init.h>                 // Needed for the macros

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int
hello_2_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, world 2\n");
    return 0;
}

static void
hello_2_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye, world 2\n");
}

module_init(hello_2_init);
module_exit(hello_2_exit);
```

Following is my make file:

```
obj-m += HelloModule.o
CROSS_COMPILE = arm-linux-gnueabihf-
ARCH=arm

KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

I have navigated to the respective folder and after trying `make all` following is the error that I am getting:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.103-v7l+'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/pi/Documents/testfolder2/HelloModule.o', needed by '/home/pi/Documents/testfolder2/HelloModule.mod'.
```

Can somebody please help me I am just stuck on this for the past two days!!

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the formatting of your question so it's readable.  See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  Also you can look at the helpful live preview of your question as you type it, to see what it will look like when you post it.  Secondly, what is the name of the source file that you created?  If you want to build a module named `HelloModule.o` then your source file **must** be named `HelloModule.c` (case-sensitive) in that same directory.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked , I had named the file as Hellomodule.c . I'll make sure to post the question with proper formatting next time. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Unlike Windows and MacOS, the default Linux filesystems are all traditional POSIX filesystems and are case-sensitive, as are the command line arguments to most programs, etc.  It's important to pay attention to this, there.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: @MadScientist, MacOS and Windows are also POSIX compatible (with older standards)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that drive letters cannot be considered POSIX compatible.  But note I said _traditional_ POSIX filesystems, which have always been case-sensitive (if you create a file `HELLO` and run `cat hello` it will fail because `hello` is not the same file as `HELLO`: on MacOS and Windows the filesystems are case-insensitive so `HELLO` and `hello` are the same file).